# How do I avoid the extra gap between the search bar and the tableview here and put a separator between the same?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My code produces the following results: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLhgQ.png), [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Vdc.png)

However I am supposed get these: 
[Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzpRs.png)

I have tried correcting the same. However I failed miserably and i don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Please help me find what could be wrong here and how I should rectify it. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class SelectCountryViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    struct CellStruct
    {
        var countryName : String
        var countryFlag : String
        var countryDialCode :   String
    }

    var cellDatas = [CellStruct]()

    var filteredCellDatas = [CellStruct]()

    var searchController : UISearchController!
    var resultsController = UITableViewController()




    var searchLoaded = false
    var isSearching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureSearchController()

        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancel))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
        self.navigationItem.title = "Select Country"

        let searchButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchButtonAction))
        searchButton.image = UIImage(named: "search")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton



        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "countries", ofType: "json")
            else
        {
            return
        }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do
        {
            let data = try Data (contentsOf: url)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
            print(json)
            guard let array = json as? [Any] else { return}
            for info in array {
                guard let userDict = info as? [String: Any] else { return}
                guard let code = userDict["code"] as? String else { print("No code found"); return}
                guard let dialCode = userDict["dial_code"] as? String else { print("No dial code found"); return}
                guard let name = userDict["name"] as? String else { print("No name found"); return}
                print("We have: ", code, dialCode, name)
                cellDatas.append(CellStruct(countryName: name, countryFlag: code, countryDialCode: dialCode))
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;


    }
    func configureSearchController()
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()


        resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0


        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = []
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey()
        searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey().cgColor

        for subView in searchController.searchBar.subviews {
            for subViewOne in subView.subviews {
                if subViewOne is UITextField {
                    subViewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.searchBarTextFieldGrey()
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
        definesPresentationContext = true

    }
    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        return true
    }
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey()
        searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey().cgColor


    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = nil
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            filteredCellDatas = cellDatas
        } else {
            // Filter the results
            filteredCellDatas = cellDatas.filter { $0.countryName.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }
        }
        resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == resultsController.tableView
        {
            isSearching = true
            return filteredCellDatas.count
        }
        else
        {
            isSearching = false
            return cellDatas.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
         var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.separatorInset.left = 15
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

            cell?.separatorInset.left = 0
        }

        if tableView == resultsController.tableView
        {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = filteredCellDatas[indexPath.row].countryName
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredCellDatas[indexPath.row].countryDialCode
            cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage (named: filteredCellDatas[indexPath.row].countryFlag)

        }
        else
        {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = cellDatas[indexPath.row].countryName
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = cellDatas[indexPath.row].countryDialCode

            cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage (named: cellDatas[indexPath.row].countryFlag)
        }


        return cell!

    }


    @objc func cancel(){
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    @objc func searchButtonAction() {

        searchLoaded = true
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.isActive = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.text = ""
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

After search bar is attached to table view it should look : [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcnG4.png)  and not [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2mTa.png)

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in `viewDidLoad()` :

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Add below line after setting up your `SearchController`:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: Throws error: Value of type 'SelectCountryViewController' has no member 'contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior'

Comment: I have tried             self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false.
It didn't work.

Comment: Thank you @iVarun but it's rigid now. I can't even see the search bar.

Comment: @AnnoThra could you please add Screen Shot  how it looks after adding above code.

Comment: check the last line. I added two images. I am getting the second with this approach.

Comment: @AnnoThra now it's issue with your NavigationBar. Make sure NavigationBar is configured properly. As NavigationBar is not visible in your first screen shot too. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLhgQ.png

Comment: It is because when search bar is active then it covers navigation bar. I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtiamBbL5QU

Comment: @AnnoThra Your question is about spacing between tableview and searchbar. Please ask different question. If this answer helps you to resolve your question please close this by accepting this answer by clicking on right sign besides answer. This will help other developers to find  correct answer. Thanks.